# View a site without a domain WITHOUT updating hosts file?

Tags: wordpress, dns, cpanel

I have a few sites I developed that I need to show my client for review. These are all redesigns of live sites, so they've had me upload them to their new hosting server, which is currently accessible via IP address because the domains are currently in use by the live sites.

I've set each site up as add-on domains in cpanel, and they all live in directories off the root, like `192.0.2.3/site1.example` (for example).

However, these are Wordpress sites, and the database references the actual domain name (`site1.example`), so that it will be all set for launch when we update the DNS to point to this server. That means you can't actually see the site at that domain unless you update your hosts file. But there are lots of non-technical people that need to review the site, and updating their hosts file just isn't an option.

I'd rather not have to do a search and replace on the database to change the domain to `192.0.2.3/site1.example` temporarily, just so they can view it. Because when we're ready for launch, I'll just have to do another search and replace to switch it back to the real URL. But it seems like that's my only option.

Is that correct, or is there another way they can view the site without me having to update all the URLs in the database?

Comment: Do you control in anyway the recursive DNS server they use? Otherwise you can install a reverse proxy (that itself will have the `hosts` file): you give anyone concerned an URL like `www.example.com/jump/site1.example` and the reverse proxy at `/jump` will just forward everything to `site1.example` that the reverse proxy can resolve without problems.

Comment: Unfortunately no. No DNS access. Sounds like I'll just do it the search-and-replace way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution here is to search and replace the URL just as you said